# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen ruby

Tags: ruby

Facing below issue eventhough the file is present in the folder.

```
H:\Ruby_test_works>ruby hurrah.rb
hurrah.rb:7:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - H:/Ruby_
test_works/SVNFolders.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
        from hurrah.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
        from hurrah.rb:4:in `each_line'
        from hurrah.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Input file (input.txt) Columns are tab separated.

```
10.3.2.021.asd  10.3.2.041.def  SVNFolders.txt
SubversionNotify    Subversionweelta    post-commit.bat
Commit message  still rake  customemail.txt
mckechney.com   yahoo.in    ReadMe.txt
```

Code :

```
dir = 'H:/Ruby_test_works'
file = File.open("#{dir}/input.txt", "r")

file.each_line do |line|
  initial, final, file_name = line.split("\t")
  #puts file_name
  old_value = File.read("#{dir}/#{file_name}")

  replace = old_value.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(initial)}, #{Regexp.escape(final)}/)
  File.open("#{dir}/#{file_name}", "w") { |fi| fi.puts replace }

end
```

I have tried using both forward and backward slashes but no luck. What I'm missing, not sure. Thanks.

`puts file_name` gives the below values

```
SVNFolders.txt
post-commit.bat
customemail.txt
ReadMe.txt
```

Comment: In the input file, the file name mentioned has space, like this 'SVN Folders.txt', but in the error the same file reads like this, 'SVNFolders.txt'. Does your file name have spaces ?

Comment: Let me get this straight... There is only **one** file in `H:/Ruby_test_works`: `input.txt`. This file contains four lines of text, each ending in another file name. You then try to open that file ... But the file **does not exist**. This is your error message. There is no such file as `H:/Ruby_test_works/SVNFolders.txt`. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ucpuzz : Sorry that was an copy and paste issue. File doesn't have name spaces

Comment: @TomLord : My apologies if the question is confusing. input.txt file has 3 columns, say 1st col - existing value, 2nd col : to be replaced value, 3 col is the file name where the replacement has to be done.

there are 5 files under : `H:/Ruby_test_works` including `input.txt`>

I'm looping thru each line of input.txt and to fetch the values that has be to replaced on the other 4 files.

Comment: Have you tried to use `File.open` instead of `File.read` on line 7? Also I could not find docs on `File.read`. What version of ruby you are using?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky `File` extends `IO`, which is where `read` is implemented: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read

Comment: Sometimes it's a pathing issue. Compare your file path with what you think the file path is with something like: File.expand_path('my_file.rb')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `file_name` contains the newline character `\n` at the end, which won't get printed but messes up the path. You can fix the issue by stripping the `line` first:

```
initial, final, file_name = line.strip.split("\t")
```

When debugging code, be careful with `puts`. Quoting its [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) reveals an ugly truth:

> Writes the given object(s) to ios. **Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence.**

Another way to put this is to say it ignores (potential) newlines at the end of the object(s). Which is why you never saw that the file name actually was `SVNFolders.txt\n`.

Instead of using `puts`, you can use `p` when troubleshooting issues. The very short comparison between the two is that `puts` calls `to_s` and adds a newline, while `p` calls `inspect` on the object. Here is a bit more details about the differences: http://www.garethrees.co.uk/2013/05/04/p-vs-puts-vs-print-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. +1 for puts vs p usage.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is not the file, but the path to the file. Consider compare the file path with what you think the file path is with something like:

```
File.expand_path('my_file.rb')
```